# Which is the best coefficient to compute a "user agreement" metric?

Tags: correlation, agreement-statistics

Let us suppose that *N* users are asked to answer **yes/no** to *M* questions.
For example:

```
     Q_1  Q_2  Q_3 ... Q_M
U_1   Y    Y    N       N
U_2   N    Y    N       N
..........................
U_N   N    Y    Y       N
```

where `U_1, U_2, ..., U_N` represent the N users, whereas `Q_1, Q_2, ..., Q_M`are the questions. Which metric is more appropriate to evaluate the "agreement" between the users?

Comment: With no other information than this, the number or proportion of questions on which users agree is to me the only metric in sight. What others do you have in mind?

Comment: @NickCox It makes sense, but I was looking for something more sophisticated.

Comment: Something more sophisticated might hinge on something extra, such as regarding Yes and No answers differently. There are many such measures in cluster analysis or numerical taxonomy.

Answer (score 2):

Using your notation of $M$ questions being answered yes $(1)$ or no $(0)$, we can calculate the percentage of observed agreement $(p_o)$ among users via the following formula

$$p_o=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{q=1}^{M}\sum_{a=0}^{1}\frac{U_{qa}(U_{qa}-1)}{U_q(U_q-1)}$$

where $U_{qa}$ is the number of users that responded to question $q$ with answer $a$, and

$U_q$ is the number of users that responded to question $q$ with any answer.

A further extension would be to adjust for how much agreement would be expected by "chance" (e.g., guessing by the users). Numerous approaches for this exist and are based on different assumptions of the process that generates that chance agreement. You can read more here:

https://github.com/jmgirard/mReliability/wiki/Agreement-or-Accuracy

https://github.com/jmgirard/mReliability/wiki/Chance-adjusted-index

Answer (score 1):

Consider a vector $v$ which represents the m answers of one user. If $u$ represents the answers of another user, then the cosine similarity of the two users measures their agreement
$$similarity = cos \ \theta = \frac{u^\intercal \cdot v}{\lVert u\rVert\lVert v\rVert} $$

This will ultimately simplify to measuring the proportion of answer the two users agree on, which makes intuitive sense.

If you take the pairwise cosine similarity of all the users, you can construct an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix of similarity scores. If you calculate the (Frobenius) norm of this matrix you could get a score for the overall dataset. An alternative might be to find the SVD of your similarity matrix and take the largest singular value.